# Word request: Agreeing in a conversation

Tags: word-requests

For example: in a conversation about food, when your friend says that the food is おいしい, then you can also say おいしいね, or そうだね.

Are there other ways you can say in agreement? Perhaps a phrase similar to 'I Agree!' or 'Yes! Really!'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally overkill (and maybe that's what you're going for) but 賛成！works pretty much like 同感。Another one I used to love to do (which in the case of food goes really well with the over-acting one finds on Japanese TV is to do) 正解！(Correct!) like they'd say on Who Wants to Be a Millionaire.

The answers in your original post are arguably the most colloquial though.　I will add that you need a certain level of fluency for this to not sound mechanic and weird.  IMHO, anyway.

Comment: This is great! And funny, at the same time! I like 正解 because it is playful when you are trying to imitate tv shows.

Comment: Cheers.  You can get some good laughs out of it, but depends a lot on the audience. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is the word 同感 which basically means "feeling the same". It can be used to in the same way as "ditto" in English.

> A: そのラーメン凄く美味しいよね。
> B: （私は、) 同感だ。
>
> A: Those ramen are so much great.
> B: I agree./ Ditto. / B just nods.

That said, there is not a lot of emotions packed in this (= 同感) expression. It merely expresses that you feel the same; just like "ditto" would.

---

For more colorful expressions, the comment from Choco describes some possible answers (more specifically related to Kansai). But you can freely use something like:

> でしょう（ね）(isn't it ? / you're right !)

to express agreement with a previously said おいしい・うまい, regardless of dialects.

Comment: @macraf, Yes, 同感 can be used as a one-noun phrase (or だ, です can be added just after). Pretty much like 正解 ou 賛成 proposé par kiss-o-matic. But since, 正解 and 賛成 have more to do with reason than with feelings I find it a bit weird to answer 賛成 or 正解 to somebody who said おいしい.

Comment: "I find it a bit weird to answer 賛成 or 正解 to somebody who said おいしい" >> そおですね、言いませんね、ふつう・・・。「おいしい！」って誰かが言ったら、関西だと、(その時に初めて食べていたら→)「ほんまや、おいしいな！」「ほんまや、めっちゃうまいやん！」「これやばい！」とか、(以前に食べたことがあるなら→)「そやろ？」「おいしいやろ？」「うまいやんな！」「やばいやんな！」とか言ってるかな。関西弁しか思いつかなくてごめんねｗ　あと、「やばい」って俗語だから、１０年後に通じなかったらごめんねｗ

Comment: @choco I'm going around looking at comment-answers and trying to encourage users to post them as answers instead. Since your comment appears to answer the question, would you like to post an answer instead?  Even though it's not a general answer, it is still an answer for 関西弁